# Rails, Rake aborted! undefined method 'active_record'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I'm sure I miss some basic thing.

I had a correctly working app in dev environment. 
Than I had some modifications that I cant correctly explain (with the migrations and tried to insert seed_dump gem).
Now every rake command drops an error:

```
C:\Programozas\Rails Apps\sorsveto>rake about
rake aborted!
undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x3e482
98>

Tasks: TOP => about => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

or

```
C:\Programozas\Rails Apps\sorsveto>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

There is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.8.rc'
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.0.1'
  gem 'shoulda-context'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0.rc.4'
  gem 'listen', '0.4.7'
  gem 'guard-livereload', '1.0.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end

# Test gems on Windows
group :test do
  gem 'rb-fchange', '0.0.5'
  gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  gem 'win32console', '1.3.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. I tried to reinstall or install 0.8.7 and remove this (now I have version 0.9.2.2). I even tried to install 0.9.2. Many combinations (more than one at a time and run bundle exec rake XY) no success.
I even tried to insert this into my gem file:

```
require 'rake/dsl_definition'
require 'rake'
```

Neither helped.
Any ideas? All help mutch appriciated.

Comment: Do you guys need more info to be able to help? Ask for it pls, I need so much the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was so basic and annoying that I feel shame to even tell.

Somehow in my application.rb my this line:

```
require "active_record/railtie"
```

commented out. 
Removed the # and worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my Gemfile had somehow gotten deleted. Maybe because I aborted a rake action with CMD-C when it was half-way..

I fixed it with `git co Gemfile`