# Rails s error: `method_missing': undefined method `active_record'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, rails-activerecord

My rails project works before. I got this error because I deleted mysql and everything associated mysql.

Then I reinstalled mysql. It got this error. Then I reinstalled ruby and rails. The error is still here. Using "rails new myapp", 
               then "bundle instal", 
               then "rails s",

I got the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on 

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
**/home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x0000000303cae8> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config/environments/development.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'**
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `class_eval'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:24:in `configure'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config.ru:in `new'
    from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/atop/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
    from /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 8):

The error is clear that in `config/environments/development.rb:23` you configure active_record which  is not loaded.

Just remove

```
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
```

Will be ok.

Comment: After I tried the suggestions below and come back to this suggestions, it works now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

`Leedy Liu` is right to some degree, but if you're getting this error when you create a new Rails app, t suggests a deeper problem with your environment

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653584/rails-rake-aborted-undefined-method-active-record), you may have `require "active_record/railtie"` commented out in your `application.rb` file. Please check to make sure this is not the case

You may have to re-install `Rails` with `ActiveRecord` to ensure the functionality is restored with your app. Have you tried this:

```
gem install bundler
gem install rails
bundle install
```

Other than that, you need to ensure Ruby on Rails is installed correctly. What env are you running? Linux or Windows?

Comment: The same error. /home/cwu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000000044dd6f0> (NoMethodError)
 from /home/cwu/Dropbox/project/web/myapp/config/envir

Comment: Ok, after this editor. My newly created (rails new myapp) works. My old app has the same error.

Answer (score 2):

As a general fix, remove all references to active_record.  Easiest way is to do a find on the root directory of "active_records", find all usages, and remove them.  I found usages in config/application.rb and config/environments/development and production.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    'gem install bundler'
```

then:
        'bundle install'
again.

See if it clears up.

Answer (score 0):

Comment `config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true` in `config/application.rb` and `config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load` in `config/environments/development.rb`.